# Table stuck in header - Word 2010

Tags: ms-word

Somehow, I got some tables inside the header and some inside the footers in the document Im working on. They are not supposed to be there, and this destroys the formatting.

How do I move a table out of the header/footer in Word 2010? They seem to be locked in there no matter what I do. I've tried copy/paste, dragging it, copy it to another document and back. Is there some settings on the table it self? Google has not found anything for me.

Comment: Could you please post your document ? I can correct it for you I think.

Comment: @edi9999 I can't do that, sorry. It is some documentation for a client. If you could just try to explain, I'd be very happy.

Comment: I see, I'm going to tell you how to proceed in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! This is how I solved the problem:

> I fixed it "manually". I just made a new document and started copying over, there was more than one table bugging. Thanks for the help anyway!

Since this question is from July 2013, and I solved it then, I'm not testing your replies. But, they might be great for other people with the same problem! They are probably better solutions than just starting over.

Answer (score 14):

I had this happen to me just a second ago and was able to figure it out - hopefully the same thing is causing the problem for you.

I clicked on the table - then "table tools/layout" in the ribbon - then "properties" - alternatively you can right click on the table and select "table properties"

Once the "table properties" box opens - click on the "table" tab (it should be automatically selected by default) - **make sure "text wrapping" is set to "none"**

That should solve the problem - it did for me at least.

Comment: And me too.  This was driving me crazy.  Nice fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Word but I know how Word Document are structured.

We're going to open the content of the header in a text Editor.

Steps:

1. Be sure to make a copy of your document before this operations, because the resulting document could be corrupted
2. Rename your file in a `.zip` file
3. Extract the zip in a folder named **document**
4. Go inside that folder, than in the **word** folder.
5. You should see a file named **header.xml** (or **header1.xml**)
6. Open it in a textEditor
7. Try to find out where the table is and remove it
8. Ensure your xml is still valid: [XML Validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)
9. Save and close your file, and zip all folders and files inside the **document** (if you zip the whole document folder, the file will be corrupted)
10. Rename the zipped file to **.docx**
11. Open the file in Word
12. If this doesn't work, you could post your Header.xml file, they should'nt be some confidential in there (or you could replace it by whatever you want)

Comment: Hmm, well, there isn't a header file. The thing is, I've not actually said I want anything in the headers, that is probably why it isn't there. But still, Word has put some tables in the headers and some in the footers.

Comment: So when you go to the header/footer tab, they is nothing to edit ? How does this table look like ? Just like an empty regular table ? Maybe you could search for all tables in your xml document (search in all xml files for `<w:tbl>`)

Comment: I fixed it "manually". I just made a new document and started copying over, there was more than one table bugging. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just changed the orientation of the page to landscape:

1. Go to page layout
2. Go to orientation
3. Select landscape

The table was still on a header, but word created a page 2 and page 1 was blank. From page 2, I just dragged the table onto page 1 and it was no longer in the header!

Then, change the orientation back to portrait (follow 2 steps above and select portrait in final step).

Hope this helps!